# textbox in a listview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, listview, textbox

I have a `ListView` that contains a dropdown, 4 textboxes and buttons. I'm looking to display the fourth textbox (which is wrapped in a span) only when the dropdown is `value=2` for each row of the `ListView`.

So for example I have 5 records displaying in the `ListView` and the 2nd and 3rd both are `value=2`

this is in my `document.ready` it presets and selects each value of the dropdown on page load. So I'm trying to display the `ZipBox` when it does this as I feel like it will be easiest but I'm open to other suggestions as well because displaying the box doesn't seem to work.

```
$('.Existing').each(function() {
    var select = $(this).attr('data');
    $(this).val(select);
    //this part doesn't work below
    if(select=="2")
    {
        $('#zipBox').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' });
}
});
```

I also need to display the textbox if the dropdown selection is changed see below Tried this but it only works on first one. Fore xample if I change the vlaue of 5th record it would make the `ZipBox` visible on the first row rather than the 5th one.

```
$('.Existing').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '2') {
        $('#ZipBox').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' });
    }
});
```

Here is the listview:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="tablesorter" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 55%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#">Country</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#">Info.</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#">Action</a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="Existing" data="<%# Eval("Type").ToString()%>"
                    class="Existing" style="width: 90px">
                    <option value="0">USA</option>
                    <option value="1">CAN</option>
                    <option value="2">MEX</option>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input size="4" type="text" id="city" value="<%# Eval("City")%>" />
                <input size="4" type="text" id="state" value="<%# Eval("State")%>" />
                <input size="4" type="text" id="Phone" value="<%# Eval("PhoneNbr")%>" />
                <span id="ZipBox" style="visibility: hidden">
                    <input maxlength="5" size="5" type="text" id="zip" value="<%# Eval("ZIP")%>" />
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <2 buttons here>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the input can be toggled (with `visibility`) so the span isn't necessary, but to toggle the span or input a `class` attribute will be needed instead of an `id` (id's supposed to be unique so using `#ZipBox` for multiple zip fields will not work)

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/emkhw/)

on your first pass (`.each()`) this will set the zip visibility, I commented the portion that sets the drop down's value to the `data` attribute since that would interrupt checking for `value = 2`

```
$('.Existing').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this), // drop down
        $thisRow = $this.closest('tr'), // the drop down's row
        $thisZip = $thisRow.find('.zip'), // the zip textbox on the same row
        $thisDataType = $this.attr('data'); // data attribute contains the type

    //$(this).val(select); // type is being set to the value

    if ($this.val() == 2) {
        $thisZip.css({'visibility': 'visible'});
    }
});
```

for the change event you can do almost the same thing, but added the `else {}` block if `MEX` is selected then changed the `zip` will hide again

```
$('.Existing').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this), // the drop down that changed
        $thisRow = $this.closest('tr'), // the drop down's row
        $thisZip = $thisRow.find('.zip'); // the zip textbox on the same row

    if ($this.val() == 2) {
        $thisZip.css({'visibility': 'visible'});
    } else {
        $thisZip.css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
    }
});
```

Comment: awesome!!! Thanks. i was wondering about the toggle since if u change to one but u clicked wrong thing and meant to be something else how owuld it change it back.awesome